# GridBagLayout Uniformity Issue

Tags: java, gridbaglayout

I have no idea what am doing wrong anymore, heres how it all looks

[image: Image of UI]

Notice the last 3 panes are incorrect in terms of alignment yet they use the same code as the first two. Heres the code.

```
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;

public class View_RegisterMember extends JDialog {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -4610105372782292470L;
private JDialog dialog;

// Panels
private JPanel pdPanel;
private JPanel addressPanel;
private JPanel cdpanel;
private JPanel memDetails;

private Border blackline;

private JLabel lblTitle;
private JLabel lblFirstName;
private JLabel lblSurname;
private JLabel lblStreetNo;
private JLabel lblStreetName;
private JLabel lblCity;
private JLabel lblPostcode;
private JLabel lblPhoneNo;
private JLabel lblEmail;
private JLabel lblMembershipType;
private JLabel lblPrice;
private JLabel lblpriceData;
private JLabel lblDob;

// textfields

private JTextField textphoneData;
private JTextField textFieldEmailData;
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private JComboBox comboBoxTitle;
private JTextField textFieldfName;
private JTextField textFieldlName;
private JTextField textFieldNumber;
private JTextField textFieldStreetName;
private JTextField textFieldCity;
private JTextField textFieldPostCode;

private JTextField textFieldDOB;
private JComboBox<String> comboBoxMemType;

private JButton btnSave;
private JPanel bdPanel;
private JLabel lblAccountName;
private JTextField textFieldAccName;
private JLabel labelSortCode;
private JTextField textFieldSortCode;
private JLabel lblAccNo;
private JTextField textFieldAccNo;

public View_RegisterMember(final JFrame frame) {

    dialog = this;

    blackline = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);
    dialog.setTitle("Member Registration");

    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0) {
            frame.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });

    GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    createBagLayouts(gridBagLayout);
    getContentPane().setLayout(gridBagLayout);

    createPersonalDetailsPane();
    createAddressDetailsPane();
    createContactDetailsPane();
    createBankDetailsPane();
    createMemberTypeDetailsPane();

    // createAppointmentsPane();
    // frame.setSize(new Dimension(335, 650));

    btnSave = new JButton("Register");
    btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        }
    });
    btnSave.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_btnNewButton = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_btnNewButton.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_btnNewButton.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_btnNewButton.gridx = 1;
    gbc_btnNewButton.gridy = 10;
    getContentPane().add(btnSave, gbc_btnNewButton);

    dialog.setResizable(true);
    dialog.pack();
    dialog.validate();
    dialog.repaint();

}

@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
private void createPersonalDetailsPane() {

    pdPanel = new JPanel();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_dpPanel = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_dpPanel.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_dpPanel.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_dpPanel.gridx = 1;
    gbc_dpPanel.gridy = 1;
    getContentPane().add(pdPanel, gbc_dpPanel);
    GridBagLayout gbl_panel = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl_panel.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 1.0};

    pdPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(blackline, "Personal Details",
            TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.ABOVE_TOP, null,
            SystemColor.inactiveCaptionText));

    pdPanel.setLayout(gbl_panel);

    lblTitle = new JLabel("Title:");
    //lblTitle.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblTitle = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblTitle.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_lblTitle.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_lblTitle.gridx = 0;
    gbc_lblTitle.gridy = 0;
    pdPanel.add(lblTitle, gbc_lblTitle);
    lblTitle.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 18));

    try {
        comboBoxTitle = new JComboBox(Controller_Registration.GetTitles());
    } catch (Exception_Database e) {
        utilities.DisplayError(e.getMessage(), dialog);
    }
    comboBoxTitle.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_comboBoxTitle = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_comboBoxTitle.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    //gbc_comboBoxTitle.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc_comboBoxTitle.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_comboBoxTitle.gridx = 1;
    gbc_comboBoxTitle.gridy = 0;
    // Minus the one to match up the SQL ids with the index
    comboBoxTitle.setSelectedIndex(1);
    pdPanel.add(comboBoxTitle, gbc_comboBoxTitle);

    lblFirstName = new JLabel("Name:");
    //lblFirstName.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblFirstName = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblFirstName.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_lblFirstName.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_lblFirstName.gridx = 0;
    gbc_lblFirstName.gridy = 1;
    pdPanel.add(lblFirstName, gbc_lblFirstName);
    lblFirstName.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 18));

    textFieldfName = new JTextField();
    textFieldfName.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_textFieldfName = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_textFieldfName.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    gbc_textFieldfName.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_textFieldfName.gridx = 1;
    gbc_textFieldfName.gridy = 1;
    pdPanel.add(textFieldfName, gbc_textFieldfName);
    textFieldfName.setColumns(10);

    lblSurname = new JLabel("Surname:");
    //lblSurname.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblSurname = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblSurname.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_lblSurname.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_lblSurname.gridx = 0;
    gbc_lblSurname.gridy = 2;
    pdPanel.add(lblSurname, gbc_lblSurname);
    lblSurname.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 18));

    textFieldlName = new JTextField();
    textFieldlName.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_textFieldlName = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_textFieldlName.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    gbc_textFieldlName.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_textFieldlName.gridx = 1;
    gbc_textFieldlName.gridy = 2;
    pdPanel.add(textFieldlName, gbc_textFieldlName);
    textFieldlName.setColumns(10);

    lblDob = new JLabel("D.O.B:");
    //lblDob.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    lblDob.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblDob = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblDob.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_lblDob.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_lblDob.gridx = 0;
    gbc_lblDob.gridy = 3;
    pdPanel.add(lblDob, gbc_lblDob);

    textFieldDOB = new JTextField();
    textFieldDOB.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_textFieldDOB = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_textFieldDOB.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    gbc_textFieldDOB.gridx = 1;
    gbc_textFieldDOB.gridy = 3;
    pdPanel.add(textFieldDOB, gbc_textFieldDOB);
    textFieldDOB.setColumns(10);

}

private void createAddressDetailsPane() {

    addressPanel = new JPanel();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_addressPanel = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_addressPanel.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_addressPanel.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_addressPanel.gridx = 1;
    gbc_addressPanel.gridy = 3;
    getContentPane().add(addressPanel, gbc_addressPanel);
    GridBagLayout gbl_panel1 = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl_panel1.columnWeights = new double[] { 0.0, 1.0 };
    addressPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(blackline, "Address",
            TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.ABOVE_TOP, null,
            SystemColor.inactiveCaptionText));
    createBagLayouts(gbl_panel1);
    addressPanel.setLayout(gbl_panel1);

    lblStreetNo = new JLabel("Street No:");
    //lblStreetNo.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
    //lblStreetNo.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    lblStreetNo.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblStreetNo = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblStreetNo.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_lblStreetNo.gridx = 0;
    gbc_lblStreetNo.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_lblStreetNo.gridy = 0;
    addressPanel.add(lblStreetNo, gbc_lblStreetNo);

    textFieldNumber = new JTextField();
    textFieldNumber.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_textFieldNumber = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_textFieldNumber.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    gbc_textFieldNumber.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_textFieldNumber.gridx = 1;
    gbc_textFieldNumber.gridy = 0;
    addressPanel.add(textFieldNumber, gbc_textFieldNumber);
    textFieldNumber.setColumns(10);

    lblStreetName = new JLabel("Street Name:");
    //lblStreetName.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblStreetName.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblStreetName = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblStreetName.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_lblStreetName.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_lblStreetName.gridx = 0;
    gbc_lblStreetName.gridy = 1;
    addressPanel.add(lblStreetName, gbc_lblStreetName);

    textFieldStreetName = new JTextField();
    textFieldStreetName.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    textFieldStreetName.setColumns(10);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_textFieldStreetName = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_textFieldStreetName.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    gbc_textFieldStreetName.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_textFieldStreetName.gridx = 1;
    gbc_textFieldStreetName.gridy = 1;
    addressPanel.add(textFieldStreetName, gbc_textFieldStreetName);

    lblCity = new JLabel("City:");
    //lblCity.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    lblCity.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblCity = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblCity.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_lblCity.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_lblCity.gridx = 0;
    gbc_lblCity.gridy = 2;
    addressPanel.add(lblCity, gbc_lblCity);

    textFieldCity = new JTextField();
    textFieldCity.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    textFieldCity.setColumns(10);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_textFieldCity = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_textFieldCity.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    gbc_textFieldCity.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_textFieldCity.gridx = 1;
    gbc_textFieldCity.gridy = 2;
    addressPanel.add(textFieldCity, gbc_textFieldCity);

    lblPostcode = new JLabel("Postcode:");
    lblPostcode.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblPostcode = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblPostcode.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_lblPostcode.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_lblPostcode.gridx = 0;
    gbc_lblPostcode.gridy = 3;
    addressPanel.add(lblPostcode, gbc_lblPostcode);

    textFieldPostCode = new JTextField();
    textFieldPostCode.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    textFieldPostCode.setColumns(10);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_textFieldPostCode = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_textFieldPostCode.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    gbc_textFieldPostCode.gridx = 1;
    gbc_textFieldPostCode.gridy = 3;
    addressPanel.add(textFieldPostCode, gbc_textFieldPostCode);
}

private void createContactDetailsPane() {

    cdpanel = new JPanel();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_cdpanel = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_cdpanel.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_cdpanel.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_cdpanel.gridx = 1;
    gbc_cdpanel.gridy = 5;
    getContentPane().add(cdpanel, gbc_cdpanel);
    GridBagLayout gbl_cdpanel = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl_cdpanel.columnWeights = new double[] { 0.0, 1.0 };

    cdpanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(blackline, "Contact Details",
            TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.ABOVE_TOP, null,
            SystemColor.inactiveCaptionText));
    createBagLayouts(gbl_cdpanel);
    cdpanel.setLayout(gbl_cdpanel);

    lblPhoneNo = new JLabel("Phone No:");
    //lblPhoneNo.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    lblPhoneNo.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblPhoneNo = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblPhoneNo.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_lblPhoneNo.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_lblPhoneNo.gridx = 0;
    gbc_lblPhoneNo.gridy = 0;
    cdpanel.add(lblPhoneNo, gbc_lblPhoneNo);

    textphoneData = new JTextField();
    textphoneData.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_textFieldEmailData = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_textFieldEmailData.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    gbc_textFieldEmailData.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_textFieldEmailData.gridx = 1;
    gbc_textFieldEmailData.gridy = 0;
    cdpanel.add(textphoneData, gbc_textFieldEmailData);
    textphoneData.setColumns(10);

    lblEmail = new JLabel("Email:");
    //lblEmail.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    lblEmail.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblEmail = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblEmail.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_lblEmail.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_lblEmail.gridx = 0;
    gbc_lblEmail.gridy = 1;
    cdpanel.add(lblEmail, gbc_lblEmail);

    textFieldEmailData = new JTextField();
    textFieldEmailData.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_textFieldEmailData1 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_textFieldEmailData1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    gbc_textFieldEmailData1.gridx = 1;
    gbc_textFieldEmailData1.gridy = 1;
    cdpanel.add(textFieldEmailData, gbc_textFieldEmailData1);
    textFieldEmailData.setColumns(10);

}

@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
private void createBankDetailsPane() {
    bdPanel = new JPanel();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_bdPanel = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_bdPanel.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_bdPanel.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_bdPanel.gridx = 1;
    gbc_bdPanel.gridy = 7;
    getContentPane().add(bdPanel, gbc_bdPanel);
    GridBagLayout gbl_bdPanel = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl_bdPanel.columnWeights = new double[] { 0.0, 1.0 };

    bdPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(blackline, "Payment Details",
            TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.ABOVE_TOP, null,
            SystemColor.inactiveCaptionText));
    createBagLayouts(gbl_bdPanel);
    bdPanel.setLayout(gbl_bdPanel);

    lblAccountName = new JLabel("Acc Name:");
    lblAccountName.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblAccountName = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblAccountName.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_lblAccountName.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_lblAccountName.gridx = 0;
    gbc_lblAccountName.gridy = 0;
    bdPanel.add(lblAccountName, gbc_lblAccountName);

    textFieldAccName = new JTextField();
    textFieldAccName.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_textFieldAccName = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_textFieldAccName.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    gbc_textFieldAccName.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_textFieldAccName.gridx = 1;
    gbc_textFieldAccName.gridy = 0;
    bdPanel.add(textFieldAccName, gbc_textFieldAccName);
    textFieldAccName.setColumns(10);

    labelSortCode = new JLabel("Sortcode:");
    labelSortCode.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_labelSortCode = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_labelSortCode.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_labelSortCode.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_labelSortCode.gridx = 0;
    gbc_labelSortCode.gridy = 1;
    bdPanel.add(labelSortCode, gbc_labelSortCode);

    textFieldSortCode = new JTextField();
    textFieldSortCode.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_textFieldSortCode = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_textFieldSortCode.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    gbc_textFieldSortCode.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_textFieldSortCode.gridx = 1;
    gbc_textFieldSortCode.gridy = 1;
    bdPanel.add(textFieldSortCode, gbc_textFieldSortCode);
    textFieldSortCode.setColumns(10);

    lblAccNo = new JLabel("Acc No:");
    lblAccNo.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblAccNo = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblAccNo.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_lblAccNo.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_lblAccNo.gridx = 0;
    gbc_lblAccNo.gridy = 2;
    bdPanel.add(lblAccNo, gbc_lblAccNo);

    textFieldAccNo = new JTextField();
    textFieldAccNo.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    textFieldAccNo.setColumns(10);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_textFieldAccNo = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_textFieldAccNo.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    gbc_textFieldAccNo.gridx = 1;
    gbc_textFieldAccNo.gridy = 2;
    bdPanel.add(textFieldAccNo, gbc_textFieldAccNo);

}

private void createMemberTypeDetailsPane() {

    memDetails = new JPanel();
    GridBagConstraints gbc_memDetails = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_memDetails.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    //gbc_memDetails.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    gbc_memDetails.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_memDetails.gridx = 1;
    gbc_memDetails.gridy = 9;
    getContentPane().add(memDetails, gbc_memDetails);
    GridBagLayout gbl_memDetails = new GridBagLayout();
    gbl_memDetails.columnWeights = new double[] { 0.0, 1.0 };

    memDetails.setBorder(new TitledBorder(blackline, "Membership Type",
            TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.ABOVE_TOP, null,
            SystemColor.inactiveCaptionText));
    createBagLayouts(gbl_memDetails);
    memDetails.setLayout(gbl_memDetails);

    lblMembershipType = new JLabel("Type:");
    lblMembershipType.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblMembershipType = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblMembershipType.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_lblMembershipType.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_lblMembershipType.gridx = 0;
    gbc_lblMembershipType.gridy = 0;

    memDetails.add(lblMembershipType, gbc_lblMembershipType);

    comboBoxMemType = new JComboBox(Controller_Member.getMemberTypes(null));
    comboBoxMemType.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 18));

    GridBagConstraints gbc_comboBoxMemType = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_comboBoxMemType.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    gbc_comboBoxMemType.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_comboBoxMemType.gridx = 1;
    gbc_comboBoxMemType.gridy = 0;

    memDetails.add(comboBoxMemType, gbc_comboBoxMemType);

    lblPrice = new JLabel("Price:");
    lblPrice.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblPrice = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblPrice.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    gbc_lblPrice.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
    gbc_lblPrice.gridx = 0;
    gbc_lblPrice.gridy = 1;
    memDetails.add(lblPrice, gbc_lblPrice);

    lblpriceData = new JLabel("");
    lblpriceData.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblpriceData = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblpriceData.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    gbc_lblpriceData.gridx = 1;
    gbc_lblpriceData.gridy = 1;
    memDetails.add(lblpriceData, gbc_lblpriceData);
    DecimalFormat ob = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

    String price = "£"
            + ob.format(Controller_Member.getMembershipTypes()[0]
                    .GetPrice());
    lblpriceData.setText(price);

    comboBoxMemType.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

            double price = Controller_Member.updatePrice(comboBoxMemType
                    .getSelectedIndex());
            DecimalFormat ob = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
            String priceLabel = "£" + ob.format(price);
            lblpriceData.setText(priceLabel);
        }
    });

}

private void createBagLayouts(GridBagLayout gridBagLayout) {

    gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0 };
    gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[] { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE };
    gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[] { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE };

}

}
```

Have I missed something so simple?

Comment: You can reduce code by adding a method that adds to panel label with text field/combobox. The same with groups.

Comment: I can tbh, but atm laziness is just getting the better of me, the rewriting is just mehh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all the calls to the method `private void createBagLayouts(GridBagLayout gridBagLayout)` except the first one (inside the dialog constructor).
These calls are overwriting your `columnWeights` settings in your panes and messing things up.
Note that the first pane doesn't have a call to `createBagLayouts` method and that's the reason why it works. The only reason why the call worked on the second pane is because it is the largest pane and therefore the one determining the entire dialog width.

Comment: thank you very much that works perfectly. I take it then column heights and what not only need to be set once ever?

Comment: In GridBagLayout the default dimensions of cells are set so the minimum and the preferred sizes of cells are taken in consideration. You only need to override this behavior by manually setting widths heights and weights when you want something out of ordinary.